# Is there an R function to make string values with slight differences uniform?

Tags: r, string, data-cleaning

Please forgive me in advance, as I am very new to using R. I have a string variable that contains many organization names that were manually entered by a number of different people for several thousand observations. As a result, there are many typos and variations on the organization names. For example, a few observations look like this:

| Organization Name | What I would like the cell to be |
| --- | --- |
| AIDS Foundation Chicago | AIDS Foundation Chicago |
| Aids Foundatio Chicago | AIDS Foundation Chicago |
| Center for Housing | Center for Housing and Health |
| Center for Housing & Health | Center for Housing and Health |
| AIDS Foundation | AIDS Foundation Chicago |
| Center for Housing and Health | Center for Housing and Health |
| Center For HOusing and Health (FHP) | Center for Housing and Health |
| AIDS FOUNDATION OF CHICAGO | AIDS Foundation Chicago |
| Aids Foundation Chicago | AIDS Foundation Chicago |

Is there a way I can use R to replace the first column to look like the second? I would tell you what I've tried, but frankly I'm not sure where to start. Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you have a lookup table of all valid names, you could try a fuzzy string matching function like stringdist::stringdist()

Comment: One step in that direction would be to use `unique` to figure out how many different variations you have. That gives you the first column. You will have to do the second column by hand if `stringdist` does not help.